# cannot import _protoc_compiler from grpc_tools

Tags: python, grpc

I've got an issue when generating code with **grpc_tools** package from my .proto file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "somepath\run_codegen.py", line 16, in <module>
    generate()
  File "somepath\run_codegen.py", line 6, in generate
    from grpc_tools import protoc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\grpc_tools\protoc.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc_tools import _protoc_compiler
```

**I've installed these dependencies from requirements.txt:**

```
Flask~=1.1
grpcio
grpcio-tools
protobuf
```

[image]

**The script file named run_codegen with the following code:**

```
from grpc_tools import protoc

def generate():
    protoc.main((
        '',
        '-I./FinancialDataScraper/protos',
        '--python_out=./FinancialDataScraper/Generated',
        '--grpc_python_out=./FinancialDataScraper/Generated',
        './FinancialDataScraper/protos/quotes.proto'
    ))

generate()
```

I don't know if should explicitly use the version number for **grpcio**, and **grpcio_tools** packages or this is related to python itself, or I missed some other dependencies to install.

Comment: did you manually create run_codegen or was this autogenerated?

Comment: Yes, I've created run_codegen manually.

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with the script itself because I got the same error when I've executed the same command via the command line.

Comment: are you sure your deps were successfully installed? have you tried running it in virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question with a screenshot of my installed dependencies.

Comment: its a similar issue as https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9108

Comment: I cannot navigate to the _proto_compiler module from the source file; the module is missing. Tried to reinstall grpcio_tools but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the issue was because I've executed the script from outside my environment, and the environment was not activated.